# XML file not being extracted in R

Tags: r

I am working on a project that requires me to go through various pages of links, and within these links find the xml file and parse it. I am having trouble extracting the xml file. There are two xml files within each link and I am interested in the one that is bigger. How can I extract the xml file, and find the the one with the max size. I tried using the grep function but its constantly giving me an error.

```
sotu<-data.frame()
for (i in seq(1,501, 100))
{
  securl <- paste0("https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/srch-edgar?text=abs-
                   ee&start=", i, "&count=100&first=2016")

  main.page <- read_html(securl)

    urls <- main.page %>%
      html_nodes("div td:nth-child(2) a")%>%
      html_attr("href")
    baseurl <- "https://www.sec.gov"
    fulllink <-paste(baseurl, urls, sep = "")

    names <- main.page %>%
      html_nodes ("div td:nth-child(2) a") %>%
      html_text()

   date <- main.page %>%
      html_nodes ("td:nth-child(5)") %>%
      html_text()

  result <- data.frame(urls=fulllink,companyname=names,FilingDate=date, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  sotu<- rbind(sotu,result)
}

for (i in seq(nrow(sotu)))

  {

  getXML <- read_html(sotu$urls[1]) %>%
    grep("xml", getXML, ignore.case=FALSE )

  }
```

Everything works except when I try to loop over every link and find the xml file, I keep getting an error. Is this not the right function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help from `dplyr` we can do:

```
sotu %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  do({
  read_html(.$urls) %>%
    html_table() %>% 
    as.data.frame() %>% 
    filter(grepl('.*\\.xml', Document)) %>% 
    filter(Size == max(Size))
})
```

or, as the type is always `'EX-102'` at least in the example:

```
sotu %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  do({
  read_html(.$urls) %>%
    html_table() %>% 
    as.data.frame() %>% 
    filter(Type == 'EX-102')
})
```

This also get rid of the `for` loop, which is rarely a good idea in R.